# How to get input parameter in MainLayout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

1. Blazor App: I have custom header logo and custom footer links that
   will change, based on the input parameter {id}.
2. Input parameter ID is used in a query to retrieve company logo, and
   footer link information from database.

The dynamic header and footer is apart of the mainlayout, how do I get the input parameter via mainlayout?

Comment: And where this id come from ? From url path, url query string, a settings ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose you've created a Company parent component which can get a route parameter to represent a company ID, the value of which is used to retrieve the company's details that may be displayed in a child component. You may define the parent component like this:

### Company.razor

```
@page "/company"
@page "/company/{ID}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Note: The two route templates above are necessary...

Answering your question...
Add this code to the MainLayout component

```
@code{

    public string ID { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // pull out the "ID" parameter from the route data
        object id = null;
        if ((this.Body.Target as RouteView)?.RouteData.RouteValues?.TryGetValue("ID", out id) == true)
        {
            ID = id?.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Note: The code above extricates the value of the ID parameter from the RouteData, and stores it in the ID property. Now you can do with it, whatever you want... including passing it to the the NavMenu Component if it's necessary there. This is how you can do it:

Add a Component Parameter property to the NavMenu Component, like this:

```
[Parameter]
public string ID { get; set; }
```

And add an ID component parameter attribute to the NavMenu component instance (located at the top of the MainLayout component. It should be now  `<NavMenu  ID="@ID"/>`

Are you happy now ?

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried it, it does not work "protected override void OnParametersSet() It does not read the ID",.. I can see the ID inside the component but not in main layout

Comment: This code works perfectly well. I've run it on my computer, as it was the hardest question I've faced here. Where did you put the OnParametersSet method ? It should be in MainLayout.razor . Put this in OnParametersSet  and view the result: Console.WriteLine($"This is the ID: {ID}"); If it still 'doesn't work', please upload your app in github, or display it here for my inspection.

Comment: Does your url look something like this: https://localhost:44362/company/123   If not, it should be like that...

Comment: I fixed it :) Everything is working! and thanks again, I appreciate your help :)