# What is causing __builder does not exist in current context error from compiler?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

"Error  CS0103  The name '__builder' does not exist in the current context"

Here is my code that causes the error:

```cs
@code {
    public void Calc()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 55; )
        {
           <div class="alert-info">

               <h3>This is the number" &nbsp;@i</h3>

           </div>
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error message from compiler]

Comment: It appears that this is a known issue, but still don't know how to resolve https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13275

Answer (score 21):

You can't render HTML in @code or @functions block. You can do this in a @{ } code bock.

Comment: Thank you, I had been writing code int he main section and swppied it over to @code and thought I swapped all the html out. Once I knew what to look for I was able to fix my issue quickly.

Comment: As for @functions MS says otherwise https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#functions but in fact you are right -- one has to stick with "@{ }" and drop all "private/public/whatever" modifiers making functions local.

Answer (score 2):

[The correct answer is at this SO link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086768/component-attributes-do-not-support-complex-content-mixed-c-sharp-and-markup)

In short you cannot mix markup with C# code inside `@code` block.

Consider make a component for reusing the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Members of the component class are defined in one or more **@code** blocks. In @code blocks.

Component members are used in rendering logic using C# expressions that start with the **@** symbol. For example, a C# field is rendered by prefixing **@** to the field name.([more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#razor-templates))

The [RenderFragment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment) delegate must accept a parameter called **__builder** of type [RenderTreeBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.rendering.rendertreebuilder) so that the Razor compiler can produce rendering instructions for the fragment.

**Sample1:**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering

@{ load1(__builder); }
@code {
    void load1(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
        @for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            <div class="alert-info">
                <h3>This is the number @i</h3>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample2:**

```
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="()=>Calc()">Action</button>
@((MarkupString)myMarkup)
@code {
    string myMarkup = "";
    void Calc()
    {
        @for (int j = 0; j < 55; j++)
        {
            myMarkup += getMarkup(j);
        }
    }

    string getMarkup(int j) {
        var myMarkup = "<div class='alert-info'>";
        myMarkup += $"<h3>This is the number {j}</h3>";
        myMarkup += "</div>";
        return myMarkup;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per ltwlf's answer, HTML markup is not allowed within the @Code block.  I received the same error, but I was positive that I had no HTML within my @code block.  However, after careful review I noted that there were HTML comment tags `<!--  ...  -->` inside my @code block.  This displays correctly as *green comments* and is easily missed - Therefore carefully review your @code block for any HTML markup if you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the "onclick" within a razor page you must prefix it with the @ symbol.

[Event Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

[image: Event handling ASP.NET Core 7]